# How to enable helpful error messages for gmake?

Tags: gnu-make

## Example

I have a gmake 4.0 from a MinGW installation, that shows no helping error messages.

For example I have this makefile:

```
# test.mk
all: somefile.c
```

Since I have no file named `somefile.c` present, it fails, but without any helpful message:

```
$ gmake -f test.mk
gmake: ***.  Stop.
```

When I add the `--debug` flag I get some hints:

```
$ gmake -f test.mk --debug
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'all' does not exist.
   File 'somefile.c' does not exist.
  Must remake target 'somefile.c'.
gmake: ***.  Stop.
```

## Expectation

For an older gmake 3.80 from another tool set, I get a helping message:

```
$ gmake-old -f test.mk
gmake-old: *** No rule to make target `somefile.c', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

## Environment

I am running these command within a `git-bash` under Windows.  I am getting a similar message, when calling `gmake` within windows `cmd`.

## Question

Are there options for `gmake` or environment variables that I might set in order to get gmake 4.0 to provide helping messages like `No rule to make target 'somefile.c', needed by 'all'`?

Comment: I have no explanation for this.  Perhaps try using `set LANG=C` and `set LC_ALL=C` before you start `make` and see if it helps.  There must be something wrong with the build of make you're using.

Comment: @MadScientist: Setting those variables doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Sounds like you have a broken build of GNU make then.  I have no other explanation.  Basically, GNU make provides an internationalization capability where it can use native languages, and the output messages you see can be shown in the local language (GNU make supports 30 different languages).  If the language cannot be recognized it defaults to English.  It looks like for some reason your version is trying to translate the output but the translation returns an empty string.  I've never seen something like this.

Comment: @MadScientist : Thanks for your efforts.  Is there a chance to check wither a fancy flag or so, whether this language support was disabled during build or if it maybe is just not able to find supporting files?  I have no knowledge about, how this language support works, but I could think of that gmake has not all strings compiled in and instead needs to search some files for the language specific strings.

Comment: It can be disabled at compile time, but if it's disabled then you'd see the English strings (the English strings are compiled into the program and used for the "C" locale, and/or if a given string cannot be translated).  Unfortunately I just don't know much about how Windows works: I don't do Windows.  You can try asking on the MinGW support lists or maybe on the make-w32@gnu.org mailing list.  You should be sure that the tags of your question reflect that it's a MinGW and gettext issue maybe someone who knows about those will help.